# SQL select data and grouping data by date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with data like this

| price | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2021-03-13 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-14 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-15 | A |
| 1300 | 2021-03-16 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-17 | A |
| 1300 | 2021-03-18 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-19 | A |
| 1500 | 2021-03-20 | A |
| 1500 | 2021-03-21 | A |
| 1500 | 2021-03-22 | A |
| 2000 | 2021-03-13 | B |
| 2000 | 2021-03-14 | B |
| 2000 | 2021-03-15 | B |
| 2000 | 2021-03-16 | B |
| 2000 | 2021-03-17 | B |

I want to query data like this

| price | startDate | endDate | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2021-03-13 | 2021-03-15 | A |
| 1300 | 2021-03-16 | 2021-03-16 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-17 | 2021-03-17 | A |
| 1300 | 2021-03-18 | 2021-03-18 | A |
| 1000 | 2021-03-19 | 2021-03-19 | A |
| 1500 | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-22 | A |
| 2000 | 2021-03-13 | 2021-03-17 | B |

my current sql below but it is not correct at all

```
SELECT MIN(date) as startDate, MAX(date) as endDate, price, type                                      
                            FROM prices 
                            GROUP BY type, price
                            ORDER BY type, MIN(date)
```

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: how are u making sure that the data appears in this order?

Comment: What's with a gap not filled with another record, i.e. when record (1300,2021-03-16,A) wouldn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using CTE, you can work the following query:

```sql
SELECT w1.price, w1.date, w2.date, w1.type FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM mytable t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2
    WHERE 
      t1.price = t2.price AND
      t1.type = t2.type AND
      DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date) = -1
  )
) w1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM mytable t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2
    WHERE 
      t1.price = t2.price AND
      t1.type = t2.type AND
      DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date) = +1
  )
) w2
ON
w1.price = w2.price AND
w1.type = w2.type AND
w1.date <= w2.date AND
NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2
    WHERE 
      t1.price = t2.price AND
      t1.type = t2.type AND
      DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date) = +1
  )
  AND
  w1.price = t1.price AND
  w1.type = t1.type AND
  w1.date <= t1.date AND t1.date < w2.date
)
```

1. Getting the smaller and larger dates of each period.
2. Joining these tables.
3. Getting rows between smaller and larger dates.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ZCh2jU44sYoegBQtoUrTC/1)

Comment: @banku. . . This is definitely not the simplest solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one simple way to handle it uses the difference in row numbers method.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, the following should work:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type, price ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM prices
)

SELECT price, MIN(date) AS startDate, MAX(date) AS endDate, type
FROM cte
GROUP BY price, type, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY type, startDate;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: It doesn't detect gaps not filled with other prices, i.e. if you remove the records with price 1300. Is this intended?

Comment: @Turo You see some edge case which is not all visible to me in the OP.  I will wait for feedback from the OP before making an edit.

Comment: I hoped you'd post a solution ;-) I couldn't find it yet...

Comment: @Turo . . . The dates have no gaps in the question.  The OP does not explain what to do in that case.  In my opinion, this answers the question and is one of the best ways to solve it.  (I can think of one simplification but it is not worth an answer.)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MIN(date) as startDate, MAX(date) as endDate, price, type    
FROM prices
GROUP BY type, price
ORDER BY MIN(date) ASC
```

This query might work in arranging data in ascending order of date

Comment: Too simple and doesn't produce expected result